# @myusersname on Mysite (Facebook)

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

My users are able to update their Facebook status by Graph API (in PHP), How can we do "*@myusersname on Mysite*" like Twitter?

i.e. picture @ https://i.stack.imgur.com/60F14.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do that using the [action parameter](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#posts)

```
$attachment = array(
    'message' => 'USERS_MESSAGE', // NB: this cannot be prefilled
    'name' => 'NAME',
    'caption' => 'CAPTION',
    'link' => 'http://mysite.com',
    'description' => 'DESCRIPTION',
    'picture' => 'http://mysite.com/mysiteimage.jpg',
    'actions' => array(array(
            'name' => '@myusersname on Mysite',
            'link' => 'http://mysite.com/myusernsme' ))
);
try { $result = $facebook->api('/me/feed/', 'post', $attachment); } catch (Exception $e) {  }
```

Comment: You're very welcome, but if you're happy with an answer it's customary to mark your question as answered giving credit where it's due. :)